# Why is the FIN flag in TCP called FIN?

Tags: networking, tcp, history, terminology, acronym

There are some flags in TCP. I already understand what other flag names come from, such as SYN stands for synchronization. I also know that FIN is used to close a connection. What I don't understand is what exactly FIN means. Is it an abbreviation like other flags? I just can't make sense of it.

Comment: I'm pretty sure FIN is just short for finish in everything I've ever studied :)

Comment: It's also French for 'end', which is probably how finish got into the English language in the first place.

Comment: @Tetsujin from Latin originally -- finish Middle English: from Old French feniss-, lengthened stem of fenir, from Latin finire, from finis ‘end.’ ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Why is the FIN flag in TCP called FIN?

`FIN` is an abbreviation for "Finish"

---

> In the normal case, each side terminates its end of the connection by sending a special message with the **FIN (finish)** bit set. This message, sometimes called a FIN, serves as a connection termination request to the other device, while also possibly carrying data like a regular segment. The device receiving the FIN responds with an acknowledgment to the FIN to indicate that it was received. The connection as a whole is not considered terminated until both sides have finished the shut down procedure by sending a FIN and receiving an ACK.

Source [TCP Connection Termination](http://www.tcpipguide.com/free/t_TCPConnectionTermination-2.htm) :